# How to map array into checkbox for React Native [TypeScript]?

Tags: typescript, react-native, checkbox, store

I am new to React Native. I am currently using TypeScript for my React Native project. Right now, I am having a difficulty on how to map array into checkbox. Below is my json file:

```
{ 
   "stud_name": "Adam",
   "sex": "male",
   "attendance": false,
   "eligibility": false
}
```

I would like to map `attendance` and `eligibility` inside the checkbox. Below is my React Native code for the checkbox.

```
export const StudentRegisterExam: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const StudentData = useContext(StudentStoreContext);

  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false;
      return;
    }
    if (response !== undefined) {
      if (response.status === 201 || response.status === 200) {
        StudentData.details = {
           name: response.data.name,
           sex: response.data.sex,
           eligibility: response.data.eligibility,
           attendance: response.data.attendance
       };
     }
   }
 }, [response]);

return (
      <View>
        <Text>{StudentData.response.name}</Text>
        <Text>{StudentData.response.sex}</Text>
        <CheckBox /> <- how should I write {StudentData.response.eligibility} into checkbox
        <CheckBox />
      </View>
 );
```

Thank you in advance. For the `StudentData`, I created a file name `StudentStore.ts` inside my store folder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully get your point. 
Mapping an array means iterating over each of it's values. But it seems you mean how to get the Data into your -Component?

The question at all is, how does your checkbox-component looks like. You should post the source-code of it... or do you use a UI-Library like `react-elements`.

In case of [`react-elements`-Checkbox](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html) you can do it like this:

```js
const { response } = StudentData;
return (
      { Object.keys(response).map(item =>
      <View>
        <Text>{response[item].stud_name}</Text>
        <Text>{response[item].sex}</Text> 
        <CheckBox
          center
          title='{response[item].stud_name}'
         checked={response[item].eligibility}
        />

      </View>
      ) }
 );
```

Hope that gives you an Idea.

Think the thing you've searched for was how to execute a loop in your JSX, isn't it?
Or was it how to put parameters into an Component?

So you can execute it within { }, but you can only use expressions there... no classical if, for or while-loops. 
So go with method-calls like yourArr.forEach, yourArr.map or ternary operator as replacement for if-conditions

Comment: I already tried your method. However, I encounter an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. `{response.map(item =>` is not working.

Comment: try `{response && response.map(item => ...)}`

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan wow! after I tried  ` {response && response.map(item => ...`, its working but unfortunately my checkbox is not appear on the screen

Comment: There is an error occur at `const { response } = StudentData;` which make my checkbox not appear on the screen. Any idea on how I can make my checkbox appear on the screen? Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I had an issue in my code. I fixed it above. For sure, you have to iterate over your `Object` with `Object.keys()`. This way it should work. Here I've also created a little example to show how it work: https://jsbin.com/javayolaqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually, that `const { response } = StudentData;` is not needed. After I remove that code,  my checkbox is appear on the screen. However, I am unable to click to my checkbox. Any idea on how to make my checkbox functional? Thank you :)